# PHP : Google App Engine On Local Platform with Codeigniter Error : Call to undefined function pg_connect()

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter, google-app-engine

I have facing issue with Google App Engine Local Platform with My **PHP** and **Codeigniter Framework** When I trying to connect with my **postgresql database**

```
Message: Call to undefined function pg_connect()
```

Filename:

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/duffler_live/webservices/system/database/drivers/postgre/postgre_driver.php
```

Comment: Do you have the PGP extension enabled in your `php.ini`?

Comment: Yes i have enabled PGP extension in my php.ini

Comment: Can you check that by running a script with just `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and show us the results

Comment: It display me version details of pdo_pgsql and module version when i run phpinfo()

Comment: Let's Discuss in Chat..